# how to reflect a database's date format using sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

How do I do something like `DBCC useroptions` in python using sqlalchemy? I need to see what's the date format used by the database. Ideally, a sqlalchemy specific solution that'll work regardless of the dialect.

Comment: AFAIK there is no generic SQLAlchemy inspection to do what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a faster way but maybe this could work.

```
# given connection to db 
conn.execute("DBCC useroptions").fetchall()
```

Comment: I was hoping for a sqlalchemy solution that wouldn't involve running a query.